# How can i install mongodb on cloud linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos, cloud, cpanel

I want to install mongodb on cloud linux `centos` . I'm using cPanel and have ssh access and terminal access  but not root access. I can't use commands like `sudo su`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. To install MongoDB in CentOS, the MongoDB repository needs to be first enabled. For this, please create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo` with any editor of your choice.

```sh
# vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo
```

Add the below entries in the created repository file, save and exit the editor.

```sh
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

2. Execute the below command to install the MongoDB package.

```sh
# yum install -y mongodb-org
```

3. Start the MongoDB service.

```sh
# systemctl start mongod
```

4. Stop or Restart the MongoDB service.

```sh
# systemctl stop mongod
# systemctl restart mongod
```

5. Check the status of the MongoDB service.

```sh
# systemctl status mongod
```

6. To check and confirm that the MongoDB service has been installed, make use of the `mongo` command to access the MongoDB shell.

```sh
# mongo
```

The below screenshot shows how the MongoDB shell looks like.
[image: enterbjbjbjb]

Comment: This requires root privileges, which is not available